# How to use populate in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections where one holds list of systems and the other holds list of battery attached to the system. I want to use populate method so that when I run the query using system id it shows me the details of battery is also shown.
My schema for system and battery are as follows.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const SystemSchema = new Schema(
  {
    serialNumber: String,
    location: String,
    BPIDs: [
      {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'batteryPack'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

const Systems = mongoose.model('system', SystemSchema);

module.exports = Systems;
```

My battery model is as follows:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const batteryPackSchema = new Schema(
  {
    systemSerialNumber: String,
    batteryID: Number,
    batteryVoltage: Number,
    totalCurrent: Number,
    stateOfCharge: Number
  {
    timestamps: true
  }
);

const BatteryPacks = mongoose.model('batteryPack', batteryPackSchema);

module.exports = BatteryPacks;
```

My query route is as follows:

```
router.get('/details/:id', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const deviceDetails = await Systems.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).populate('batteryPack').lean();
    return res.status(200).send({
      deviceDetails
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).send(error.stack);
  }
});
```

On running query through postman it shows the following error:

> MongooseError: Cannot populate path `batteryPack` because it is not in your schema. Set the `strictPopulate` option to
> false to override.
> at getModelsMapForPopulate

Comment: you should populate BPIDs

Comment: Thank you so much! You are a life saver! I am new to document referencing and I misunderstood the documentation.

Comment: I guess you got the answer, now you should close this question or post an answer (after 2 days of asking the question) explaining what was wrong. This helps the site by preventing this question from coming in unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was passing wrong argument inside populate method. The code is working flawlessly now.

```
const deviceDetails = await Systems.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).populate('BPIDs').lean();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const deviceDetails = await Systems.findOne({ _id: req.params.id },{},{
  populate: { path: 'BPIDs' },
  lean: true,
})
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.